# SMO problem: Sequence and series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Problem on Series and Sequences (SMO Test):

> For each positive integer $n \ge 1$ , we define the recursive relation given by $a_{n+1}=\cfrac{1}{1+a_n}$.

> Suppose that $a_1=a_{2012}$.Find the sum of the squares of all possible values of $a_1$.

How to do this? I do not know how to approach it at all. What does recursive relation mean?

Comment: recursive relation means each term (except the initial) is a function of the preceding terms

Comment: Oh so like: $a_{2012} = \cfrac {1}{1+a_{2011}}$ right, that's the function?

Comment: Yes, $a_{2012}$ is a function of $a_{2011}.$  Do you know how to show this converges and/or what the possible limits are?

Comment: No:( I am on an elementary level, I almost know nothing about limits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint :**

Lets calculate first few terms.

$$a_2=\frac{1}{1+a_1}$$
$$a_3=\frac{1}{1+a_2}=\frac{1+a_1}{2+a_1}$$
$$a_4=\frac{1}{1+a_3}=\frac{2+a_1}{3+2a_1}$$
$$a_5=\frac{1}{1+a_4}=\frac{3+2a_1}{5+3a_1}$$
$$a_6=\frac{1}{1+a_5}=\frac{5+3a_1}{8+5a_1}$$

It can be shown by induction that
$$a_n=\frac{F_n+F_{n-1}\, a_1}{F_{n+1}+F_n \, a_1} \tag{$n \ge 2$}$$

where $F_n=0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,\ldots$ are Fibonacci numbers.

Then $a_{2012}=a_1$ is a quadratic in $a_1$ and using Vieta's, sum of squares of its roots can be found.

Answer (score 2):

$$A_{n+1}=\frac{1}{1+A_n}\implies A_{n+1} A_n+A_{n+1}=1~~~(1)$$
Let $A_n=\frac{B_{n-1}}{B_{n}}$, in (1) then
$$B_{n+1}=B_n+B_{n-1},$$
which is like Fibonacci sequence.
Next, let $B_n =x^n$ to get $x=1+x^{-1} \implies x=(1\pm\sqrt{5})
/2=a,b$. So $$B_n= P a^n +Q b^n \implies A_n=\frac{a^{n-1}+R~ b^{n-1}}{a^{n}+R ~ b^{n}}.$$ The constant $R$ can be determined by a given condition.